# Interop type 'ObjectPickerHelper2Lib.ADObjectPickerClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead

Tags: c#, winforms, com-interop, winforms-interop

I have a Visual C++ COM project that I need to add to my C# WinForm project.

I have added the library to my project and the Interop wrapper was added correctly, but when I build, this error occurs:

```
error CS1752: Interop type 'ObjectPickerHelper2Lib.ADObjectPickerClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.
error CS0143: The type 'ObjectPickerHelper2Lib.ADObjectPickerClass' has no constructors defined
```

The line of code that has the problem is:

```
ObjectPickerHelper2Lib.IADObjectPicker picker = new ObjectPickerHelper2Lib.ADObjectPickerClass();
```

When I right click on ADObjectPickerClass and choose "Go to definition" option, this is shown:

```
#region Assembly Interop.ObjectPickerHelper2Lib.dll, v1.0.0.0
// C:\WorkingFolder\Proyectos\OmniLogin\OmniMaster\obj\Debug\Interop.ObjectPickerHelper2Lib.dll
#endregion

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ObjectPickerHelper2Lib
{
    [ClassInterface(0)]
    [Guid("E064BB22-22CE-4E01-BB63-10EF4058CAF9")]
    [TypeLibType(2)]
    public class ADObjectPickerClass : IADObjectPicker, ADObjectPicker
    {
        public ADObjectPickerClass();

        [DispId(10)]
        public virtual dynamic ADObjectsColl { get; }
        [DispId(7)]
        public virtual string ComputerName { get; set; }
        [DispId(6)]
        public virtual uint DownLevelFilterFlags { get; set; }
        [DispId(8)]
        public virtual uint InitInfo_OptionFlags { get; set; }
        [DispId(2)]
        public virtual uint ScopeFlags { get; set; }
        [DispId(1)]
        public virtual uint ScopeTypeFlags { get; set; }
        [DispId(3)]
        public virtual uint UplevelFilterFlags_Both { get; set; }
        [DispId(4)]
        public virtual uint UplevelFilterFlags_Mixed { get; set; }
        [DispId(5)]
        public virtual uint UplevelFilterFlags_Native { get; set; }

        [DispId(9)]
        public virtual void InvokeDialog(int hWnd);
    }
}
```

And even more, Intellisense does show the class constructor. I am using VS 2012.

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Jaime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that it was because when the COM reference was added, the properties of the reference had Embeded Interop Types in True. I changed to False and it worked.